# Sending SMS with java application

Tags: java

Good evening my colleagues I hope you are well please I need to integrate an api that will help me to send SMS and CALL from my java application I have to find one called Ozeki Java SMS SDK but I can not integrate it to my app please if someone can help me find a solution and thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check this one: https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/sms
It's not really difficult to use.

Here's the official example given to create a class SmsSender:

```
// Install the Java helper library from twilio.com/docs/java/install
import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message;
import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class SmsSender {

// Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "your_auth_token";

public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
    Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

    Message message = Message
            .creator(new PhoneNumber("+14159352345"),  // to
                     new PhoneNumber("+14158141829"),  // from
                     "Where's Wallace?")
            .create();
}
```

}

Please note that you need to register in order to have an account token.

Comment: Only hyperlink can't be an answer, if this hyperlink becomes obsolete, your answer will become worthless.

Comment: @AmitBhati , I edited my answer. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thank you sir of your answer, actually I worked with Twilio and I did, I try to follow the same tutorial of official site of twilio but my problem is that the company requires to work with OZEKI NG - SMS GATEWAY you will find below my code with Twilio Getway.